# Why does my render not show my light source?

Tags: rendering, animation, light

I have a sun that lights up my scene perfectly fine in my object view, but when I render it is completely dark.

[image: Viewport]
[image: render]

There is nothing between my sun and the camera. I've moved it all around the scene but no luck.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QZQS0aWk9VPzbxpME0iTw9sCazKQy4k3/view?usp=sharing://) is my blender file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a sphere that is hidden in viewport but that will be rendered, as we see in the *Outliner*. Note that even if you move your sun inside it won't light your scene, the location of the sun is not taken into account, so you need to either hide your sphere in render or find another solution:

[image]

Comment: I'm so stupid! Thank you! I will accept your answer as soon as the timeout is complete.